# Regular expression - get value from URL

Tags: java, regex

I need to get this string from URL - "start=100" , start can change from 0 to 1000+.
I have tried regular expressions like -

```
    Pattern p5 = Pattern.compile(".*start=[0-9]+.*");
    Pattern p6 = Pattern.compile(".*start=\\d+.*");
    Pattern p7 = Pattern.compile(".*start=.*");
    Pattern p8 = Pattern.compile(".*(start=[0-9]+).*");
```

Nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Use `start=\\d+` without enclosing it in `.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `(` and `)` to one of your first 2 regex examples or if you use your 4<sup>th</sup> example, you can get the output you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     String url = "http://localhost:8080/x?start=100&stop=1000";
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(start=[0-9]+).*");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
     if ( m.find() ) {
         // m.group(0) - url
         // m.group(1) - the first group (in this case - it's unique) 
         System.out.println(m.group(1));
     }
}
```

Output:

```
start=100
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the URL exists in your code (maybe it's not a String but an [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html)) you might use some pieces from this snippet.

```
URI uri = new URI("http://localhost:8080/x?start=10&stop=100");
String[] params = uri.getQuery().split("&");
for (String param : params) {
    if (param.startsWith("start=")) {
        System.out.println(param);
        break;
    }
}
```